# Python virtualenvwrapper not creating empty environment when used with Fedora 20

Tags: python, fedora, virtualenvwrapper

I installed [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) using the following steps in Fedora 20:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
$ export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
$ export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
$ source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
$ mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 test
```

So far so good, but when I check the environment, test, that I created it included all the existing python dependencies on my system. Here's a small sample of what's included when the virtualenv is created:

```
$ pip freeze
tornado==2.2.1
urlgrabber==3.10.1
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.6
virtualenv-clone==0.2.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.3.1
```

I've never had this issue with Ubuntu so it makes me think the problem is related to how virutalenvwrapper is interacting with Fedora 20. Please let me know what you think.

EDIT: Included the virtualenv section of my .bashrc file after a suggestion to add --no-site-packages

```
# Virtualenvwrapper                                                            
alias pip="pip-python"                                                         
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/virtualenvs 
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'                                      
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: Is it possible that somewhere there's a virtualenv.ini or some other `VIRTUALENV_` environment variable setting the `--system-site-packages` option?

Comment: I tried that but no luck. updated the question with my .bashrc

Comment: Is it possible there's anything goofy in your `path/to/virtualenv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages/easy-install.pth` ?

Comment: @Iguananaut not that I can tell, I've been able to get this working on Ubuntu 12.04, 13.04, & 14.04 without problems. On Fedora, I installed using yum install python-virtualenv. Then pip install virtualenvwrapper.